# Comparative vs. Superlative While Comparing Two Items

Tags: word-usage, comparative-constructions, superlatives

In his book section 176, 3rd ed., Swan says:

> Elder brother/sister are used when **a person has only *one*
>   brother/sister who is older**; eldest is used when there are more. An
>   elder son/daughter is the older of  two; an eldest son/daughter is the
>   oldest of two or more.

That was not clear enough; I don't see that [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/elder-eldest-or-older-oldest). Does that mean you can only use it if you have only one sister that is older than you (you don't have two or more sisters who are older than you ), or you can only use it when you talk about the youngest sister (out of two or more) that is older than you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big.  Bigger. Biggest.

There can be only one "biggest" (and only one eldest sister|brother).

There can be several "bigger" (or several elder sisters|brothers).

I believe what Swan means to say is that one does not use *eldest* when there are only two siblings.  If you have two apples, one of them is not the bigg*est* of the two but the bigg*er* of the two.

Comment: That's what I believe, but because elder/eldest have a special use and special grammar, and because of Swan's note I am having some doubts, and needed a conformation preferably by citing references or clarification from knowledgeable natives speakers like you.

Comment: You know what I think I am mistaken about my comment and still confused. Just let me gather up my thoughts and comment again!

Comment: How many thoughts do you have? Two? or Three? :-)

Comment: They do NOT have special use and grammar. It's a matter of comparative/superlative.

Comment: Wouldn't you say:"let me pull my thoughts together"! I'll ask you about elder stuff in a moment ;)

Comment: Yes, that was idiomatic. I was joking about two/three apples|siblings.

Comment: Thank you @TRomano. I get it now after a second reading of Swan's words. Anyway, I had to ask here to clear all the doubts.